# Updating of data SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have been parsing data. I receive data and compare them with the data in my database. Which command should I use so that only non-existing data can be inserted? I.i if some data already exists in the database, then nothing should be inserted.

Comment: Do you plan to write C# code using ADO.net or a stored procedure on the database side?

Answer (score 0):

You can check existence of data in `sql` using `if exists`.

if you want to insert data which is already not in table you can use something like this.

Let say its a `users table`

```
if not exists(select 1 from tbluser where Userid = 1)
 Insert into tbluser(col1,col2,col3) values (val1,val2,val3)
```

You can add other `columns` in `where` condition using `and` if required.

Comment: That's fine for one row, but the OP seems to be looking for the `MERGE` statement, or `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.